# Adding a pause to Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-workflow

I am trying to capture data on a page, which only appears on the page a few seconds after the initial page has loaded. When I run the below code, it comes back with **Loading...** which is what it says on the page at the very beginning, however I need to add logic to this below, so when run it will wait until it doesn't say **Loading...** and then do a match of the actual song (or other data) that is displayed after **Loading...**.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://www.2dayfm.com.au" -UseBasicParsing -SessionVariable mysession
$rawstationdata = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://www.2dayfm.com.au" -WebSession $mysession
$null = $rawstationdata -match '\s+id\s*=\s*"nowPlayingInfo"\s*>(.*)<\Wspan';$matches[1]
```

The logic I need to add is wait until it no longer says **Loading...** and also wait no longer than 30 seconds (as a timeout) in case it never changes from saying **Loading...**

I need to use the **UseBasicParsing** option as I need to isolate this from Internet Explorer, also I need to use **Invoke-WebRequest** and not the IE method as this will be run in Azure automation as a workflow.

Comment: I've checked out the site, and they serve the' loading 'message using Javascript and a rewrite when the form is done loading. Probably the best way to do this is with a webkit or Internet Explorer object. I'll take a stab in the morning!

Comment: Please expand on 'can't use Internet Explorer' for me.  They're most likely using Node.js or something similar, which is a flexible networking client using JavaScript.  The song information is being updated on the HTML document by JavaScript.  JS needs somewhere to execute such as in a browser.  If we don't have a browser, we don't get JavaScript, meaning we don't get the song title.

Comment: I am running this using Azure automation. However previously in the script, I used **$ie = New-Object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application** and **$ie.navigate('http://www.2dayfm.com.au/')** with some RegEx on this, but I don't think this is possible in Azure automation to add COM objects.